# Laravel 5.5 Pagination Link After Jquery Search

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Before starting let me say I have seen many links on this and other forums related to my problem but I cant seem to work around. So my problem is I have a **view** page where on start records are loaded. Now I also have around 4 - 5 input fields to search and show results on the same page. I am using jquery for that. Now my problem is as on page load there are some default data that is populated along with the pagination link therefore when i search using jquery that pagination link remains there and it is not updated as per my  returned results. 
Below I am giving the codes that I am Currently working with
First the View Page

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-responsive display" id="industry_list">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Sl.No.</th>
                      <th scope="col">Prop Name</th>
                      <th scope="col">Industry Name</th>
                      <th scope="col">Industry Address</th>
                      <th scope="col">Contact</th>
                      <th scope="col">District</th>
                      <th scope="col">Industry Category</th>
                      <th scope="col">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <?php $i=1; ?>
                    @foreach($industries as $industry)
                        <tr class="success">
                          <th scope="row">{{$i++}}</th>
                          <td class="info">{{$industry->prop_fname}} &nbsp; {{$industry->prop_lname}}</td>
                          <td class="info">{{$industry->industry_name}}</td>
                          <td class="info">{{$industry->industry_address}}</td>
                          <td class="info">{{$industry->contact}}</td>
                          <td class="info">{{$industry->district}}</td>
                          <td class="info">{{$industry->category}}</td>
                          <td class="info">
                            <a href="#" class="edit_industry" data-id="{{$industry->industry_id}}" >
                              <i class="fas fa-pen-square"></i>
                              EDIT
                            </a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                  </tbody>
                   <tfoot>
                     <tr>
                       <td colspan="8">{{ $industries->render() }}</td>
                     </tr>
                   </tfoot>
                </table>
```

Now the Controller Code for Populating on Page Load

```
public function search() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $industries = IndustryAction::paginate(5);
    return view('search', compact('user', 'industries'));
}
```

The below is the Method called by jquery for Searching

```
public function searchIndustry(Request $request){

    if($request->ajax()){
        $output = "";
        $i=1;

        if($request->query_category == 'industry_name') {
            $industries_name = DB::table('industries')->where('industry_name', 'LIKE','%'.$request->query_value.'%')
                               ->paginate(5);

        } else if($request->query_category == 'proprietor_name') {
            $industries_name = DB::table('industries')->where('prop_fname', 'LIKE','%'.$request->query_value.'%')
                                ->orWhere('prop_lname', 'LIKE','%'.$request->query_value.'%')->paginate(5);

        } 
        if($industries_name) {
            foreach ($industries_name as $key => $industry_name) {  
            $output .= '<tr class="success">'.
                    '<th scope="row">'.$i++.'</th>'.
                    '<td class="info">'.$industry_name->prop_fname.' &nbsp;'. $industry_name->prop_lname.'</td>'.
                    '<td class="info">'.$industry_name->industry_name.'</td>'.
                    '<td class="info">'.$industry_name->industry_address.'</td>'.
                    '<td class="info">'.$industry_name->contact.'</td>'.
                    '<td class="info">'.$industry_name->district.'</td>'.
                    '<td class="info">'.$industry_name->category.'</td>'.
                    '<td class="info"><a href="#" data-id="'.$industry_name->industry_id.'"  class="edit_industry" " >
                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></i>EDIT</a></td>'.
                    '</tr>';    
            }

            return Response($output);
        } else {
        return Response()->json(['no'=>'No Data']);
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly below is Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
// SEARCH QUERY ALL EXCEPT DATE
$(".search-query").on("keyup", function() {
  //$("tfoot tr td").html('');
  $value = $(this).val();
  $search_id = $(this).attr('id');
  if($search_id == 'search_industry_name') {
    $query_category = 'industry_name';
  } else if($search_id == 'search_proprietor_name') {
    $query_category = 'proprietor_name';
  } else if($search_id == 'search_address') {
    $query_category = 'industry_address';
  } else if($search_id == 'search_district') {
    $query_category = 'industry_district';
  } else if($search_id == 'search_category') {
    $query_category = 'industry_category';
  } else if($search_id == 'search_type') {
    $query_category = 'industry_type';
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'searchIndustry',
    data: {
        '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val(),
        'query_value':$value,
        'query_category':$query_category,
    } ,
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
     $('tbody').html(data);
    }   
  })      
});
```

So as u can see I cannot in any way modify or update my pagination though the search functionality is working fine. 
**Any Modifications to make the Pagination Work will be appreciated**

Comment: It's great if you post code not an image!

Comment: @HirenGohel let me know which code u want. I will post that immediately

Comment: It's useful to see and understand to other users too!

Comment: @HirenGohel Done!!! please check and suggest

Comment: You can refer this: http://www.expertphp.in/article/laravel-5-ajax-pagination-with-jquery-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are always pulling the same data,

If I were you, I would use [Datatables](https://datatables.net/), specially if you are showing the details in a table .. here is [Yajra Laravel Package](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/)

saves alot of time an effort and you have a lot of control.

### Code

Create a blade view under the name of **resources/views/articles/load.blade.php** with this code

```
<div id="search" style="position: relative;">
@foreach($industries as $industry)
<th scope="row">{{$i++}}</th>
<td class="info">{{$industry->prop_fname}} &nbsp; {{$industry->prop_lname}}</td>
<td class="info">{{$industry->industry_name}}</td>
<td class="info">{{$industry->industry_address}}</td>
<td class="info">{{$industry->contact}}</td>
<td class="info">{{$industry->district}}</td>
<td class="info">{{$industry->category}}</td>
@endforeach
</div>
{{ $articles->links() }}
```

After that the controllers:
I'm assuming here that you have 2 methods and 2 routes: ajax(search) and the main(page)
      // you must return the $industries in Page controller function as well

```
  //in your ajax controller function check if it is ajax, then render

if ($request->ajax()) {
    return view('search', compact('user', 'industries'));
        return view('articles.load', ['industries' => $industries, 'user' => $user])->render();  
    }

//In your blade collect the data
  //Check if there is actually data .. the use of page function $industries variable
                @if (count($industries) > 0)
                      //your code to the show the result
                      <div class="industries">
                    @include('searchIndustry')
                      </div>
                      //rest of your code
            @endif
```

finally the ajax part which include as well the push state for the pagination:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.pagination a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#search a').css('color', '#dfecf6');
        $('#search').append('<img style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 100000;" src="/images/loading.gif" />');

        var url = $(this).attr('href');  
        getArticles(url);
        window.history.pushState("", "", url);
    });

    function getArticles(url) {
        $.ajax({
            url : url  
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('.industries').html(data);  
        }).fail(function () {
            alert('something went wrong.');
        });
    }
});

</script>
```

[here is a good example on it](https://gist.github.com/tobysteward/6163902)

[and another one.](https://laraget.com/blog/how-to-create-an-ajax-pagination-using-laravel)

Comment: Thanks a lot... really appreciate the time u have taken.

Comment: always glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong! **How?** When you are performing search using jQuery you are only updating the content inside `<tbody>` using `ajax` request and your pagination links are never updated.

You should instead render the complete table view with pagination links inside it from `searchIndustry()` method. This way whenever you would perform a search on client side your pagination links would also be updated with your data.

So you need to change your approach! I can't write the complete code for you but I hope this explanation may help you understand your problem.

**EDIT**
*As you insisted if there is solution with this approach then here is something that you can try;*

For that first you should understand that you are only returning HTML part inside of `<tbody>` and pagination comes in `<tfooter>`, so you may need to return whole table's HTML from your controller. e.g you can add `<thead>` section before loop and footer section after loop. In order to load pagination you will write something like this inside your `<footer>` part.

```
$output .= '<tr>
  <td colspan="8">'. $industries->render() .'</td>
</tr>';
```

`$industries->render()` will output the HTML for pagination. This way pagination will also be available when you would replace HTML from AJAX request for table. In jQuery you will need to replace `<table>` HTML instead of `<tbody>`.

Comment: Yes i thot of that but i am unable to do that. I tried to do pass the $industries->render() from my server side but it gives me an error. So a code for only that part may be helpful

Comment: It is always better to move your html code to a partial view and render that in your search method rather than writing all html inside your controller.

Comment: Yes I completely agree with your suggestion... but i wanted to know if that can be done. If yes then how